# Why do I need to allocate double size for texture when rendering to texture and then render back to screen?

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to apologize for the confusing title. I will explain more detailedly here.

I am learning framebuffer through [this](https://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-OpenGL/Framebuffers.) web side.

There we want to create a framebuffer for off-screen rendering and then render it back to the screen as one image. After trying out coding by myself and also copy from its [source code](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/4.advanced_opengl/5.1.framebuffers/framebuffers.cpp), I found the rendered-back image on screen are rendered strangely.

With quite a lot rereading and observation I find the displayed image only captured 1/4 of the original one (the one rendered offscreen), which is the bottom-left part. I guess it's probably because of Mac's retina display. So I set this

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 2 * SCR_WIDTH, 2 * SCR_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB,
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
```

and also change the buffer storage settings to

```
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, 2 * SCR_WIDTH, 2 * SCR_HEIGHT);
```

`width` and `height` are originally set without doubling. I get the expected result. The window is created without doubling width and height.

Can anyone explain the theory behind it? Why do I need to double the width and height for off-screen rendering while the actual window is kept on the original width and height settings.

Comment: I'm guessing HiDPI mode retinal display doubles window width and height.  You need to use glfwGetFramebufferSize to get the actual size.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood something, one of the uses of off-rendering is to obtain a larger image that can be downsampled into the screen size. The final image should have higher quality / better antialiasing. Perhaps you're missing the downsampling step? (Which, by the way, can be done using simpel OpenGL interpolation Nearest or Linear when rendering the texture)

Comment: You need to set glViewport again before drawing the buffer to the screen. Set it when rendering to the framebuffer with your double dimension and again before rendering to the screen, with the unchanged screen dimensions. Beware of your window size callback changing the viewport.